# Spring Boot Jackson defaultImpl with JsonTypeInfo

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I am trying to handle all types of Jackson exceptions that turn up during REST API requests in a Spring Boot application. If something cannot be serialized, `JsonMappingException` is thrown. I handle this exception, build the field path that cannot be serialized (using `exception.getPath`) and return this information.

Now, I have some classes that implement the same interface (polymorphism) and have to work with them during a request. This means I also expose them to the REST API and can be included in the request/response body. Here is the interface:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
    property = "service",
    defaultImpl = DefaultNotificatorPresentation.class,
    visible = true
)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = EmailNotificatorPresentation.class, name = "email")
})
public interface NotificatorPresentation {
    String getService();
}
```

Basically, there are different types of notificators which all have different **service** (email, sms, etc). This property is used for the `@JsonTypeInfo`. Everything works as expected until I started testing if `JsonMappingException` is thrown correctly with the JSON subtypes.

`JsonMappingException` is thrown for all properties (eg. when malformed) and `InvalidTypeIdException` when **service** is not any of the available types (only email at the moment). I would like to tell the user the available options for the service property (when string is given but does not match the available types - email, sms, etc) and that it is malformed when no string is provided (object or array for example).

I came up with a solution that uses `defaultImpl` of **@JsonTypeInfo** and uses a custom class with custom validation annotation and `ConstraintValidator` that handles it.

```
public class DefaultNotificatorPresentation implements NotificatorPresentation {
    // implementation of getService() and validation annotation
}
```

The annotation has a default message - `available services are only email, sms`. That way, every time the default implementation is created (always when an invalid service is given by the user) there will be a validation error. This approach works when the property `service` in the json request is of type **string** - `"not found service"` for example.

But when `object` (`{ "example": true }`) is set to the **service** property, the `defaultImpl` class is created twice. The first instance is given property service `"{"` **(the first character of `{ "example": true }`)**. The second one service is just `null`. This creates 2 validation exceptions but **must** throw `JsonMappingException`.

Do you have any ideas on how this can be solved? I can even use a totally different approach that handles Jackson polymorphism.